# fortran. нахождение локального минимума в матрице

Tags: массивы, fortran, матрицы

помогите пожалуйста исправить

```
program matrix74
implicit none
integer,allocatable,dimension(:,:)::mat
integer::i,j,m,n,k
logical::locmin
print*,'enter the size of the matrix (NiM):'
read*,n,m
allocate(mat(m,n))
call fill_array(n,m,mat)

do i=1,m
  do j=1,n
    if (locmin(mat,m,n,i,j) .eqv. .true.) mat(i,j)=0
  end do
end do

do i=1,m
  write(*,15)(mat(i,j), j=1,n)
end do
15 format(100i10)
deallocate(mat)
end program

!this function finds local minimum
function locmin(mat,m,n,i,j)
integer,allocatable,dimension(m,n)::mat
integer::i,j,m,n
locmin=.false.
  if (i>1) then
   if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i-1,j)) locmin=.false.
  end if
  if (i<m) then
   if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i+1,j)) locmin=.false.
  end if
  if (j>1) then
   if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i,j-1)) locmin=.false.
  end if
  if (j<n) then
   if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i,j+1)) locmin=.false.
  end if
  if ((j>1) .and. (i>1)) then
   if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i-1,j-1)) locmin=.false.
  end if
  if ((j<n) .and. (i<m)) then
   if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i+1,j+1)) locmin=.false.
  end if
  if ((j>1) .and. (i<m)) then
   if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i+1,j-1)) locmin=.false.
  end if
  if ((j<n) .and. (i>1)) then
   if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i-1,j+1)) locmin=.false.
 end if
end function

subroutine fill_array(n,m,mat)
implicit none
integer::i,j,n,m
integer,dimension(m,n)::mat
do i=1,m
  do j=1,n
    write(*,10)'enter value of ar_',i,j
    read*,mat(i,j)
  end do
end do
10 format(1a,1i1,1i1)
end subroutine
```

gfortan выдает такую ошибку

```
gfortran -c matrix74.f95
matrix74.f95:25:19:

 function locmin(mat,m,n,i,j)
                   1
Error: Allocatable array ‘mat’ at (1) must have a deferred shape or assumed rank
matrix74.f95:28:7:

 locmin=.false.
       1
Warning: Extension: Conversion from LOGICAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1)
matrix74.f95:30:36:

    if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i-1,j)) locmin=.false.
                                    1
Warning: Extension: Conversion from LOGICAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1)
matrix74.f95:33:36:

    if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i+1,j)) locmin=.false.
                                    1
Warning: Extension: Conversion from LOGICAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1)
matrix74.f95:36:36:

    if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i,j-1)) locmin=.false.
                                    1
Warning: Extension: Conversion from LOGICAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1)
matrix74.f95:39:36:

    if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i,j+1)) locmin=.false.
                                    1
Warning: Extension: Conversion from LOGICAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1)
matrix74.f95:42:38:

    if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i-1,j-1)) locmin=.false.
                                      1
Warning: Extension: Conversion from LOGICAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1)
matrix74.f95:45:38:

    if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i+1,j+1)) locmin=.false.
                                      1
Warning: Extension: Conversion from LOGICAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1)
matrix74.f95:48:38:

    if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i+1,j-1)) locmin=.false.
                                      1
Warning: Extension: Conversion from LOGICAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1)
matrix74.f95:51:38:

    if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i-1,j+1)) locmin=.false.
                                      1
Warning: Extension: Conversion from LOGICAL(4) to INTEGER(4) at (1)
matrix74.f95:5:15:

 logical::locmin
               1
Error: Return type mismatch of function ‘locmin’ at (1) (LOGICAL(4)/INTEGER(4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно изменить две строки в программе.

Ниже приведён патч, который эти изменения содержит.

```
--- matrix74.f90.orig   2017-08-01 20:27:12.174692414 +0700
+++ matrix74.f90    2017-08-01 20:25:54.039437989 +0700
@@ -23,8 +23,9 @@

 !this function finds local minimum
 function locmin(mat,m,n,i,j)
-integer,allocatable,dimension(m,n)::mat
+integer,dimension(m,n)::mat
 integer::i,j,m,n
+logical::locmin
 locmin=.false.
   if (i>1) then
    if (mat(i,j)>=mat(i-1,j)) locmin=.false.
```

Во-первых, декларация `logical::locmin` действует только внутри тела основной программы. В теле функции `locmin` эту декларацию нужно повторить, чтобы компилятор не выдал предупреждений о неявном преобразовании типов. По умолчанию locmin - целое число, поскольку в теле функции отсутствует декларация `implicit none`.

Во-вторых, массив `mat` в функции locmin, это массив, передаваемый в качестве параметра, а не массив, память для которого будет выделена в теле функции оператором `allocate`, поэтому здесь вместо декларации

```
integer,allocatable,dimension(m,n)::mat
```

необходима декларация

```
integer,dimension(m,n)::mat
```